# Why is ctrl-t inserting weird text instead of opening a new tab in fzf/vim?

Tags: vim, fzf

I use [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) (installed via [vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim)) to search files in my current directory. Usually pressing `ctrl-t` will open a file in a new vim tab, but instead of working as I expected, `ctrl-t` is suddenly just inserting ";5;116~" into the fzf search.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some searching, I found a [somewhat related reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/e0l694/ctrlv_ctrlkey_instead_of_key_gives_275ascii_code/) that recommends adding the following to your vimrc:

```
let &t_TI = ""
let &t_TE = ""
```

This solved it for me.

For more information about what this does, type `:help modifyOtherKeys` into vim.

Edit:

Credit @Jorengarenar, you can do it in one line:

```
set t_TE= t_TI=
```

Comment: In one line:`set t_TE= t_TI=`

Comment: Mind that after each update of Vim and your terminal, you should check if you can remove it from config to enable `modifyOtherKeys` back, as it's quite useful feature (e.g. without it, combination `<M-S-a>` won't be distinguishable from `<M-a>`)

Comment: @Jorengarenar Great advice! Thanks you